# ProjectTo Automapper ASP.NET Core

Tags: automapper

I am using ProjectTo function of AutoMapper 5.2.0 in asp.net core.
I have already initialized my mappings at startup class. But it is throwing exception :
Mapping not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Map in startup.cs

```
Mapper.Initialize(config => {
    config.CreateMap<source, Destination>().ReverseMap();      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initialization, however, I would recommend you to use the configuration by profile approach especially if you are interested in testing you code.

Could you please add more details to the question?

This is a typical configuration with static methods

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ClassEntity, ClassDto>().ReverseMap();
        });

         ...
    }
```

[Here you can find a good answer step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-setup-automapper-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: please add more details in your answer