# AutoMapper dependency injection with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

> Error: No parameterless constructor for AutoMapperConfiguration

I am using the nuget package [automapper DI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/)

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration : Profile
{
    private readonly ICloudStorage _cloudStorage;

    public AutoMapperConfiguration(ICloudStorage cloudStorage)
    {
        _cloudStorage = cloudStorage;

        // Do mapping here
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage, AzureStorage>();
    services.AddAutoMapper(); // Errors here
}
```

How do I use the automapper DI with parameters?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275196/6583901) helps

Comment: @Dr.Fre Doesn't allow parameters in automapper constructor

Comment: @MartinDawson is right. You can only inject into custom resolvers and converters.

Comment: A complete answer with an example [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299926/7487135)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you are able to add DI parameters to `Profile`s. Part of the logic behind this may be that these are only instantianted once, so services registered through `AddTransient` would not behave as expected.

One option would be to inject it into an `ITypeConverter`:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfiguration()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationModel>().ConvertUsing<ExampleConverter>();
    }
}

public class ExampleConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceModel, DestinationModel>
{
    private readonly ICloudStorage _storage;

    public ExampleCoverter(ICloudStorage storage)
    {
        // injected here
        _storage = storage;

    }
    public DestinationModel Convert(SourceModel source, DestinationModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // do conversion stuff
        return new DestinationModel();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage, AzureStorage>();
    services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

Comment: indeed it's not recommended to inject into profiles: https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/

Comment: Will, so we do not need to add anything else to ConfigureServices to setup DI for Automapper? I tried the same code as you had shown but Automapper failed to resolve the typeconverter.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try this on your **Startup.cs**, if `AddAutoMapper` is an an extension that you built, then add the code below to your extension.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfiguration (provider.GetService<ICloudStorage>()));
    });

   services.AddSingleton(mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
  }
```

Comment: `services.AddAutoMapper` is a method from the NuGet package linked in the question. https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/

Comment: am not sure, cause I use automapper extensively on all my .net core projects, and I did not or have not included any such statements.. To configure automapper, all i have/had to do are those few lines above, that said I inject IMapper into my class's constructor there after to use the same.

Comment: I'm simply answering the "if AddAutoMapper is an an extension that you built" part - we know that it isn't a custom-built one in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I found one solution to resolve this.

Create one list of types before add profile and pass it in the parameter.

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration : Profile
{
    private readonly ICloudStorage _cloudStorage;

    public AutoMapperConfiguration(ICloudStorage cloudStorage)
    {
        _cloudStorage = cloudStorage;

        // Do mapping here
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var types = new List<Type>();
    services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage, AzureStorage>();
    services.AddAutoMapper((provider, cfg) =>
    {
        var storage = new AutoMapperConfiguration(provider.GetService<ICloudStorage>());

        types.Add(storage.GetType());
        cfg.AddProfile(storage);
        //others profiles

    }, types);
}
```

Comment: check this out: https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/. it's not recommended.