# AutoMapper in ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7

Does someone know if there's any way to use AutoMapper with ASP.Net Core 2.0?
There's no extension for IServiceCollection.

And optional question, does anyone tryed to work with AutoMapper with .Net Framework 4.7 or .Net Standard 2.0?

Comment: AutoMapper works with  ASP.Net Core 2.0. Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: Ugh! It turns out I did not added AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection. I've added only AutoMapper :/

@Win Thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Automapper in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-setup-automapper-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: A complete answer with an example [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299926/7487135)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out you need to add both: 

 - AutoMapper

 - AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

or only the 2nd one (which have dependency to the 1st one).

Answer (score 5):

You can create an `AutoMapperProfile.cs` then add to `startup.cs` like code below

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Abc, AbcEntity>();
    }              
}
```

Add to `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`

```
//Automapper profile
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>());
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above you need the AutoMapper, and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection Nuget packages.

Then in your Startup ConfigureServices method if you just add the service using:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

This will scan all assemblies within the execution context looking for classes that inherit the Automapper.Profile class and automatically add these to the AutoMapper configuration.