# How to add AutoMapper to DI in .Net core 2.0 Console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, automapper

I try to use [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/6.2.2) in my .Net Core 2.0 Console Application. My class looks like this:

```
public class AutoGetCurrency
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    public AutoGetCurrency(IMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    ....
}
```

I tried to add services into **Main** method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    services.AddTransient<IMapper>();
    ....
}
```

But I have the next error *'One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)'*

Please tell me how to add AutoMapper to use DI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add this nuget package [AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) to your project and add `AutoMapper` to your `ServiceCollection` like this

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddAutoMapper(mapperConfig => mapperConfig.AddProfiles(GetType().Assembly))
ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: Can you say how do you use IMapper instance inside Main method?

Answer (score 4):

Install the 'AutoMapper' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection' package from NuGet.

Implement User and UserDTO class for mapping from User to UserDTO:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Implement an interface and a class for doing Mapping operation as follows(don't forget using AutoMapper):

```
public interface ICustomMapper<T>
{
    T MapUserToUserDTO();
}
public class CustomMapper : ICustomMapper<UserDTO>
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    public CustomMapper(IMapper mapper) =>
        this.mapper = mapper;
    public UserDTO MapUserToUserDTO()
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
           Id = 5,
           Name = "Iman"
        };
        UserDTO userDTO = mapper.Map<UserDTO>(user);
        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

After that create a RegisterServices method for doing Dependency Injection in your project and a DisposeServices method for disposing of the service provider.

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AutoMapperProject
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegisterServices();
            ICustomMapper<UserDTO> service = 
            _serviceProvider.GetService<ICustomMapper<UserDTO>>();
            UserDTO userDTO = service.MapUserToUserDTO();
            DisposeServices();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello AutoMapper!");
        }
        private static void RegisterServices()
        {
            var collection = new ServiceCollection();
            collection.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
            collection.AddScoped<ICustomMapper<UserDTO>, CustomMapper>();
            // ...
            // Add other services
            // ...
            _serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        private static void DisposeServices()
        {
           if (_serviceProvider == null)
           {
              return;
           }
           if (_serviceProvider is IDisposable)
           {
              ((IDisposable)_serviceProvider).Dispose();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to map a concrete class that implements IMapper.
I followed Automapper documentation and it worked fine, it would be more efficient to show their documentation than writing you code there and I don't want copy / paste their sample

http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

But it would be like this: `services.AddTransient<IMapper,YourconcreteClass>();`