# Configuring AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-2.2, automapper-8

I am trying to use automapper 8.0.0 to fill a list of `WorkViewModel`.
This list is getting data from the `Work` class out of the database using entity framework.

How ever it looks like something is going wrong with initializing as throwing follows error:

> InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized

What am I doing wrong?

I have setup the following code!

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Function being called:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkViewModel>> GetAllAsync()
{
    IList<Work> works = await _context.Work.ToListAsync();

    IList<WorkViewModel> viewModelList = Mapper.Map<IList<Work>, IList<WorkViewModel>>(works);

    return viewModelList;
}
```

Configuration:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<WorkViewModel, Work>();
        });
    }
}
```

WorkViewModel:

```
public class WorkViewModel
{
    public int WorkID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Tumbmail { get; set; }
    public string Discription { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string PreviewLink { get; set; }
    public string GitLink { get; set; }
    public string DownloadLink { get; set; }

    public int DetailID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Banner { get; set; }
    public string Documentation { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Work Model:

```
public class Work
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client name")]
    public string Client { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Discription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Thumbmail")]
    public byte[] Tumbmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preview Link")]
    public string PreviewLink { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Git Link")]
    public string GitLink { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DownloadLink")]
    public string DownloadLink { get; set; }


    public WorkCategory workCategory { get; set; }
    public WorkDetailed WorkDetailed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Check [the docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. how did i miss that Doc! thank you so much!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Automapper in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-setup-automapper-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: A complete answer with an example [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299926/7487135)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only adding `services.AddAutoMapper();` to the `ConfigureServices` method would not work for you. You have to  configure `AutoMapper` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And also don't forget to install the `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` nuget package.