# ASP.NET Core 2.2: Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper'

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

***ASP.NET Core (Version: 2.2.102)***

I am building an API to return Portos and Especies, but anytime that I access /api/portos (as defined in the controller), I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate
>   'fish.Controllers.PortosController'.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, so any help is appreciated.

---

**Models**

---

*Especie.cs*

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace fish.Models
{
    [Table("Especies")]
    public class Especie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public Porto Porto { get; set; }
        public int PortoId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Porto.cs*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace fish.Models
{
    public class Porto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Especie> Models { get; set; }

        public Porto()
        {
            Models = new Collection<Especie>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Controller**

---

*PortoController.cs*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using fish.Controllers.Resources;
using fish.Models;
using fish.Persistence;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace fish.Controllers
{
    public class PortosController : Controller
    {
        private readonly FishDbContext context;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        public PortosController(FishDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet("/api/portos")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<PortoResource>> GetPortos()
        {
            var portos = await context.Portos.Include(m => m.Models).ToListAsync();

            return mapper.Map<List<Porto>, List<PortoResource>>(portos);
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller>Resources**

*PortoResources.cs*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace fish.Controllers.Resources
{
    public class PortoResource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EspecieResource> Models { get; set; }

        public PortoResource()
        {
            Models = new Collection<EspecieResource>();
        }
    }
}
```

*EspecieResource.cs*

```
namespace fish.Controllers.Resources
{
    public class EspecieResource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**More Relevant Code**

---

*Stratup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddDbContext<FishDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
}
```

*MappingProfile.cs*

```
using AutoMapper;
using fish.Controllers.Resources;
using fish.Models;

namespace fish.Mapping
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Porto, PortoResource>();
            CreateMap<Especie, EspecieResource>();
        }
    }
}
```

*FishDbContext.cs*

```
using fish.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace fish.Persistence
{
    public class FishDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FishDbContext(DbContextOptions<FishDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Porto> Portos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You will have to use automapper package as shown below:

```
Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

This will also in turn install the Automapper nuget package if you don’t have it already.

Then, inside your ConfigureServices method of your startup.cs, you will have to add a call to it as shown below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

Refer [this blog for more details.](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/)

**EDIT:**

There is very nice description [from this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-setup-automapper-in-asp-net-core)

You need to add code like below in startup.cs.

You have missed to add IMapper in DI.  Please refer add Singleton call from below code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // .... Ignore code before this

   // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddMvc();

}
```

**EDIT: 06-07-21:**
Refer this blogpost which explains how to use [AutoMapper with latest .NET](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/06/17/configure-automapper-for-asp-net-core-api-app/)

Comment: `IMapper` should be scoped, not a singleton

Comment: Been a minute since I started a new project and needed to include AutoMapper. Got a depreciation warning when I added services.AddAutoMapper(); to startup.cs. Your edited answer was extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: After wasting almost full day and found your answer and for sure edited part is very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

In case you are using .NET CORE 5. First go to nuget packages, find and install AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection[image]

Then you should extend Profile from Automapper and write mappings for your classes. Something like this below[image]
Then you should add Automapper in ConfigureServices method in Startup class.This
typeof(CommonMappingProfile) can be omitted if your nuget package for AutoMapper is in the same project as your mapping profile class.

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(CommonMappingProfile));
```

Comment: Give a code snippet would be great rather than a picture.

Comment: this is picture of my code , so basically it is similar

Comment: @mapaic96 If you give code snippet it would be easier to copy and paste the code.