# Why I get exception when I try to use AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I use AutoMapper in my .NET CORE 2.2 project.

I get this exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. 
>   Mapping types:
>   SaveFridgeTypeModel -> FridgeType
>   College.Refrigirator.Application.SaveFridgeTypeModel ->
>   College.Refrigirator.Domain.FridgeType

On This row:

```
var fridgeType = _mapper.Map<SaveFridgeTypeModel, FridgeType>(model);
```

Here is defenition of FridgeType class:

```
public class FridgeType : IEntity , IType
{
    public FridgeType()
    {
        Fridges = new HashSet<Fridge>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //Description input should be restricted 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fridge> Fridges { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is defenition of SaveFridgeTypeModel class:

```
public class SaveFridgeTypeModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I add this row:

```
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

To ConfigureServices function in Startup class.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add mappin configuration to the post.

Here is mapping configs class:

```
public class ViewModelToEntityProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToEntityProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SaveFridgeTypeModel, FridgeType>();
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get the exception above?

Comment: you need to configure mappings first, see : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40275195/1875256

Comment: As the error says there is no map from `SaveFridgeModelType` to `FridgeType`.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius please see update

Comment: Is `ViewModelToEntityProfile` in the same asssembly as `Startup`? By writing `AddAutomapper(typeof(Startup))` you basically said only take maps from this assembly

Comment: @Michael you need to check the type of model, if you are using Entity Framework it could be using a proxy

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius thanks for answer. ViewModelToEntityProfile  in another project.Is it can be a reason?How do I config AddAutomapper()  if ViewModelToEntityProfile   in another proj?

Comment: I mean path of least resistance i guess would be to do `AddAutomapper(typeof(ViewModelToEntityProfile))`

Comment: @Michael no problems, I added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the type from the assembly where your maps are when registering automapper with DI.

```
AddAutomapper(typeof(ViewModelToEntityProfile));
```

If you had multiple assemblies with maps - you could use another overload:

```
AddAutomapper(typeof(ViewModelToEntityProfile), typeof(SomeOtherTypeInOtherAssembly));
```

Answer (score -1):

After creating mapping config class you need to add the AutoMapperConfiguration in the `Startup.cs` as shown below:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // .... Ignore code before this

   // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new ViewModelToEntityProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddMvc();
}
```