# Use DTOs and AutoMapper in a simple ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, dto

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I have built an ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core appplication using Code First approach when creating the database.

Now, I want to use DTOs and AutoMapper in this simple app.

In the code below you may find the **Employee.cs** from Models folder:

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(250)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required.")]
        [DisplayName("Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        [DisplayName("Emp. Code")]
        public string EmpCode { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string Position { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        [DisplayName("Office Location")]
        public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

Below you may find the **EmployeeController.cs** file:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmployeeContext _context;

        public EmployeeController(EmployeeContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Employee
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Employees.ToListAsync());
        }


        // GET: Employee/Create
        public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return View(new Employee());
            else
                return View(_context.Employees.Find(id));
        }

        // POST: Employee/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit([Bind("EmployeeId,FullName,EmpCode,Position,OfficeLocation")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (employee.EmployeeId == 0)
                    _context.Add(employee);
                else
                    _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employee);
        }


        // GET: Employee/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            var employee =await _context.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

Additionally, you may find below the **Startup.cs** file:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Employee}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

What changes should I make to my app in order to use DTOs and AutoMapper?

Please let me know whether you need other files from the app.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your .net core version?

Comment: please try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803583/12609535 No idea someone has down voted without specifying any reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up Automapper in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-set-up-automapper-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps.

1. Create your **EmployeeDTO.cs**

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
}
```

2. Install the corresponding NuGet package

`Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

Note : If we install the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection package, it will automatically install the AutoMapper package for us since it references it.

3. Create MappingProfile.cs

Add `using AutoMapper;`

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
          CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDTO>();
          CreateMap<EmployeeDTO, Employee>();
    }
}
```

4. Configure the services. Let’s do it in the Startup.cs class.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

5. First, we inject the mapper object into the controller. Then, we call the Map()method, which maps the Employee object to the EmployeeDTO object.

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
     private readonly EmployeeContext _context;
     private readonly IMapper _mapper;

     public EmployeeController(EmployeeContext context,, IMapper mapper)
     {
         _context = context;
         _mapper = mapper;
     }

     // GET: Employee
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {

        List<EmployeeDTO> employees = _mapper.Map<List<Employee>, List<EmployeeDTO>>(await _context.Employees.ToListAsync());
        return View(employees);
     }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted your answer, but you are registering AutoMapper wrong. Whole sense of using `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` NuGet package is to leverage extension methods it provides for `IServiceCollection`. Calling `.AddAutoMapper()` like shown in [here](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core), also registers other services like value resolvers etc., which you would have to register manually.

Comment: See the [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) if you will.

Comment: @Prolog ```services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));``` . this is correct right.

Comment: Yes, `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup))` is fine as long as OP keeps Mapping Profiles in the same assembly as `Startup` class,  but generally it should be fine.