# Automapper Returns an unlisted object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

```
var company = _companyManager.GetAll();
var result = _mapper.Map<IDataResult<List<CompanyListDto>>>(company);
```

When I use something other than List while using Automapper, I get the **Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.** error.

How can I map another object out of the list?

The operation is as follows.
[Code logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP92u.png)

**I solved the problem** I solved it as follows. Thanks for your answers.

```
var result = _mapper.Map<IDataResult<List<CompanyListDto>>>(company.Data);
```

Comment: Show us how you declare your map please

Comment: I edited the subject and added a picture.

Comment: The error message is telling you what map to create.

Answer (score 1):

Your automapper is unable to find the configurations for the type of mapping you are trying to do. I guess you have not done your configurations. First of all you need to specify the mapping configurations per the domain. This can be done in two ways.

1. Using profiles (Dependency injection) [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275196/9524580)
2. Using the static method

If you are using the static method. configure it in the `startup.cs`so it will be initialized when the app is started. [For more details](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html#where-do-i-configure-automapper)

eg:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

To do custom configurations, you can use the following

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.property, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.property))
});
```

**Note:** Automapper will map the the source and destination based on the corresponding naming conventions and types. Therefore, if they are different, you have to explicitly configure them in your configuration file.

Comment: I did it using the first method. I had installed a return mechanism called IDataResult. When I getAlAll listed, IDataResult <List <Company >> returns. I don't get an error when I return it as normal List in GetAll method. So _mapper.Map <List <CompanyListDto>
But when I return as IDataResult, I get _mapper.Map <DataResult <List <CompanyListDto>> error.

Comment: Did you configure the dataResult with <List<CompanyListDto>> in your automapper configuration?